# Chronometer - Action Script 2.0 Local Storage

Tags: flash

1º. Sorry my english :)
2º. Im newbie on this, so be nice please!
Local Storage - Action Script 2.0 on Adobe Flash.
I have a FLA file, with a Chronometer of Records, Days, hours, minutes and seconds. The thing is, i wanna to save the time on local storage, I tried but it did not work.
Can u help me please?

Here´s the code:

```
stop(); // stop the scene animation
timerClip.stop(); // stop the movieclip animation

// initialise variables
var day:Number = 121;
var hour:Number = 23;
var minute:Number = 59;
var second:Number = 47;
var record:Number = 000;

timerClip.onEnterFrame = function() {


if (this._currentframe == 30) {     
    second += 1;


    // SECONDS
    if (second > 59) {          
        second = 0;
        seconds.text = "0" + second;
        minute += 1;            

        // MINUTES
        if (minute >= 10) {
            minutes.text = minute;
        } else {
            minutes.text = "0" + minute;
        }

        // HOURS
        if (minute > 59) {
            minute = 0;
            minutes.text = "0" + minute;                
            hour += 1;

            if (hour >= 10) {
                hours.text = hour;
            } else {
                hours.text = "0" + hour;
            }
            }
        // DIAS
        if (hour > 23) {
            hour = 0;
            hours.text = "0" + hour;                
            day += 1;

            if (day >= 10) {
                days.text = day;                
            } else {
                days.text = "00" + day;
            }   

        }
    } else {            
        if (second >= 10) {
            seconds.text = second;
        } else {
            seconds.text = "0" + second;
        }

    // RECORDS
    if (record > day) {         
        record = record;
        records.text = 0 + record;
        } else {
            records.text = day;
        }   

    }       
}
}
```

Here is the .Fla
https://www.4shared.com/file/PtZpnH2eca/chronometer.html

Ty all !

Comment: You need to explain the issue more clearly, pointing out what you have tried and what the expected result is. Also, put the relevant code in your question as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - a _minimal_ complete verifiable example. I practically guarantee no one is going to download & run a random file from an anonymous file-sharing service.

Comment: Ok im gonna try.
Its a sign of "Days without injuries". The chronometer works fine, and the record too.
Im trying to save the data of every VAR, so if i close the swf and open again, the last numbers will appear, and not 000:00:00

Comment: I tried using :
    
`var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test");`

But I broke the whole code, and now I went back to the original version

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you'd be getting an error, but if you declared & retrieved your `SharedObject` on the root timeline, after your initial variables:

```
var day:Number = 121;
var hour:Number = 23;
var minute:Number = 59;
var second:Number = 47;
var record:Number = 000;

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("record");

if (so.data.record) {
    record = Number(so.data.record);
    trace(record);
}
```

This should sit outside of your `onEnterFrame` function, otherwise you'll be attempting to call it 30 times per second. Assuming `record` has been committed to your SharedObject, it will trace it as expected.

On your **Record** buttons, add the following to the `on (release) {}` functions:

```
so.data.record = record;
so.flush();
```

Since `so` is already declared on the root, this will write the appropriate value to the SharedObject every time you click the buttons. The next time you run SWF, it will load from local storage.

Comment: @PabloSureda If it works, remember to come back and accept the answer! :)

Comment: @PabloSureda You'll have to provide more details than 'result is negative'.

Comment: Sorry @indextwo ! I was working on something else.
I dont know, when i close the SFW (already exported), and open it again... the time is 0:00:00 again. Its like nothing its saved.
Im gonna give up, mabye this is advanced for a nwb like me :(